# Handling route errors in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I understand how to set up my own routes, but how does one handle routes that fall through the cracks of the routing table?  I mean, I guess the default `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route could be a generic catchall, but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.  I like letting my users know they've requested data/a 'page' that doesn't exist.

Is this where the `[HandleError]` filter comes in?  How does that work, exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your route is not found, you want to handle it as a normal [**HTTP 404**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) error.

If you only add the `[HandleError]` attribute to your class or action, MVC will look for an `Error` view in your views folder.

You could also add an `ErrorController` or even a static page and add this to your `Web.config`:

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/PageNotFound/" />
</customErrors>
```

Or you could handle the HTTP 404 in your `Global.asax.cs` and route to an `ErrorController` programmatically. That's how I generally do it:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ex = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    var routeData = new RouteData();

    if (ex.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
    {
        var httpException = (HttpException)ex;

        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 404:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "PageNotFound");
                break;
            default:
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "GeneralError");
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "GeneralError");
    }

    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
    routeData.Values.Add("error", ex);

    IController errorController = new ErrorController();
    errorController.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
}
```

Comment: You need to add `Server.ClearError()` in order to stop the YSOD page from turning up or customErrors configuration to override the output you generate using the errorController.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "PageNotFound",
                "{*catchall}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "PageNotFound" }
                );
```

Than make an action in a controller like this:

```
        public ActionResult PageNotFound()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Sorry, the page you requested does not exist.";
            return View();
        }
```

This route sould be added last, that way it will catch any request that can't be mapped.

`HandleError` attribute is used to catch exceptions that may occure within controller actions.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that.. if you try to render child action @Html.Action(routeValues) with wrong values, it will render `PageNotFound` action as `PartialView` without actually reporting any exception.