# MVC 6 no exception thrown for undefined routes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a very basic asp.net MVC 6 app with basic routing, and I have a custom ErrorController to route errors to certain views.

I am expecting however that when the user types in an URL that does not exist, an exception is thrown (and I can handle it). However, no exception is thrown when I type in some random URL, I just get a blank page. I'm pretty sure this worked in similarly in MVC < 6.

The error handling itself works fine if I just throw an exception in a controller.

**Startup.cs (partially)**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv, IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(HandleException);
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes => MapRoutes(routes, appEnv));
}


private static void MapRoutes(IRouteBuilder routes, IApplicationEnvironment env)
{
    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "default",
       template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
       defaults: new { controller = "main", action = "index" });          
}

private static void HandleException(IApplicationBuilder errorApp)
{
    #pragma warning disable CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
    errorApp.Run(async context => HandleErrorContext(context));
    #pragma warning restore CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
}

private static void HandleErrorContext(HttpContext context)
{
    var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
    var exception = error.Error;
    if (exception == null)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("../error/external");
    }
    else if (exception is ExpirationException)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("../error/expired");
    }
    else if (exception is HttpException)
    {
        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        int code = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        context.Response.Redirect("../error/external?code=" + code);
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("../error/external");
    }
}
```

Comment: Not seeing where you include custom `ErrorController` in the pipeline. Am I missing something in your code?

Comment: I have another method (below what I pasted) that handles that, which works fine if I manually throw an exception. The problem is that no exception is thrown at all so it never gets to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to my question, but I've got the workaround from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4833519/2713516 working. I'm still wondering why asp.net is not throwing a 404 though.

```
           routes.MapRoute(
                "PageNotFound",
                "{*catchall}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "PageNotFound" }
                );
```

Comment: This is actually how I do it myself. I route it to my error controller's not found action where I do logging and display my custom view.

Answer (score 1):

You can show user-friendly error pages by adding the **StatusCodePages** middleware to the pipeine. `In Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationEnvironment appEnv, IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc(routes => MapRoutes(routes, appEnv));
}
```

The response body should be generated by re-executing the path `/error/{0}`.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{            
     [HttpGet("{statusCode}")]
     public IActionResult Error(int statusCode)
     {     
           //switch (statusCode)
           //{  
           //    return different views...
           //}

           Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
           return View("Error", statusCode);
     }
}
```

Thats how you can show a 404 error page or any other error page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I already have that solution in place, the ,problem is that no exception is ever thrown, so it never gets to my 'handle exception' -method

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: @user2713516 requesting an undefined route does not throw an exception so UseExceptionHandler will not be executed, as I typed in my answer, you need to add UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute middleware

Comment: I tried your solution by adding the UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute but when I type in some random url I still get a blank page.

Comment: @user2713516 you need an error controller as shown to be able to return a custom 404 page, when  UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute executes /error/404. Your HandleException has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Hi, I have an errorcontroller in place like your code, doesnt get hit though. Ill keep the solution as mentioned but thanks for the ideas :)